# What is the difference between exit(0) and raise(SIGTERM)

Tags: c++, ios, c, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to terminate my app on some particular event. Why would one use exit(0) or raise(SIGTERM) over the other?

Also since exit(0) returns EXIT_SUCCESS to the host, what does SIGTERM do? Is it always failure?

Comment: @William Pursell
you might know the answer..

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should look into `try/catch/throw`, the exception mechanism built into C++.

Comment: @NikitaP `raise` is never used because it's not portable. The C standard has this nugget: *"The complete set of signals, their semantics, and their default handling is implementation-defined"*.

Comment: For reference, Apple guidelines state that an app should never terminate voluntarily. IE, don't call `exit` or `raise` unless you have an unrecoverable error.

Comment: @user3386109 The "complete set" is "implementation defined", but  [`raise()`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14.2.1) and [`SIGTERM`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14) are conforming standard C.  Still, using `raise(SIGTERM)` instead of `exit()` or simply `return` from `main()` is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exit` causes the program to terminate with normal exit status, with value given by the argument to `exit`, in your case 0.

`raise` raises a signal, which may be caught. If it's not caught or blocked then the default action is carried out. For `SIGTERM`, the default action is *abnormal* termination, and the signal that caused it is visible in the program's exit status.

What consequences this has for iOS applications, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks Is there a preference to one over the other, and why?

Comment: Unless your program has encountered some error condition that requires it to exit, you should always exit with successful exit status, by `exit(0)` or just returning 0 from `main`. There is almost never any reason to `raise(SIGTERM)`. It sounds like you're not very familiar with the language so I'm confused where you even learned about `raise`, which is likely completely useless and inappropriate on iOS and in most contexts except certain types of systems programming.

Comment: @NikitaP: If your program is exiting normally, use `exit(0)` or `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`. If your program has encountered an error it would like to report to the thing that invoked it, but it can exit normally, use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` or some other status with `exit`. If your program has encountered a severe error and cannot exit normally, use `abort()`. This is not needed in normal applications; it may lose pending data in file buffers. There is generally no need to use `raise(SIGTERM)` unless your program is already handling signals for other reasons and you want to tie into the code for that.

Comment: Actually, if your program is exiting normally, you should use the `return` statement from `main()`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Returning from `main` may be wasteful. It may require going through normal function returns, which may do things like releasing dynamically allocated memory. But doing that calls `free`, which records the released memory in the internal data structures, which may be scattered throughout memory, which changes pages, which may cause swapping, resulting in the process pausing for several seconds while it is trying to exit. Calling `exit` directly will flush buffers and terminate, avoiding the unnecessary bookkeeping of deallocating memory that is about to be wiped away anyway.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: If there is any housekeeping that does need to be done, it can be accomplished by registering `atexit` handlers that will be called when `exit` is called. They can do the necessary clean-up tasks without requiring the program to traverse back through its entire call hierarchy. (Microsoft Word 2008 takes ten seconds to quit on macOS 10.15.6 on a late 2016 MacBook Pro, after it was **just** opened with no other user interaction. I do not know the aforementioned is the cause, but the philosophy is there.)

Comment: Yes I am unfamiliar with these and didn't know if we should use raise at all. I am still unclear on why raise is never used.

Comment: @NikitaP Where did you even learn about `raise` and why do you think it should be used?

Answer (score 1):

Sending `raise( SIGTERM )` by default causes an "abnormal termination", which means many things done in a normal program termination are not done.  Per the [C 11 standard's **7.22.4.4 The exit function**](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.4.4)

> **Description**
>
> 2 The `exit` function causes normal program termination to occur. No
>   functions registered by the `at_quick_exit` function are called. If a
>   program calls the `exit` function more than once, or calls the
>   `quick_exit` function in addition to the `exit` function, the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> 3 First, all functions registered by the `atexit` function are called,
>   in the reverse order of their registration, except that a function
>   is called after any previously registered functions that had already
>   been called at the time it was registered. If, during the call to any
>   such function, a call to the `longjmp` function is made that would
>   terminate the call to the registered function, the behavior is
>   undefined.
>
> 4 Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed, all
>   open streams are closed, and all files created by the `tmpfile` function
>   are removed.
>
> 5 Finally, control is returned to the host environment. ...

None of that will happen if you call `raise(SIGTERM)` unless you add a signal handler that will somehow invoke `exit()`.  And note that you can NOT simply call `exit()` directly from a signal handler as the `exit()` function is not async-signal-safe.

Note especially "all open streams with unwritten buffered data are flushed".  If that's not done, you risk losing data.

And, as noted, any temporary files created by your program will not be cleaned up.

In C++ code, objects with `static` storage duration are destroyed in a standard program termination.  That will not happen in an abnormal termination caused by `raise( SIGTERM )`.  So any cleanup that those objects perform in their destructors will not be done.